# How to get mean value of every month in such dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, group-by

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJzFu.png)

```
time                 A100   A101   A102
2017/1/1 0:00   
2017/1/1 1:00
2017/1/1 2:00
...
2017/12/31 23:00
```

I have a dataframe as shown above, which includes 24 hours daily records in 2017. How can I get every month's mean value of every column?

Comment: Can you please post the code, not an image?

Comment: Please show what you have tried from your research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st convert your `time` column to datatime in pandas by using `to_datetime`, then we using `groupby`

```
df.time=pd.to_datetime(df.time,format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
GMonth=df.groupby(df.time.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the data type for the time column is parsed correctly, use `dtypes` to verify it.

Next step would be just:

```
df.resample("M", how='mean')
```